# How can I change the contents of a picker on selection?

Tags: maui, converters, picker

My problem is that in some MAUI page I have a picker like so:

```
<Picker
    x:Name="pickerTravelOrder"
    Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="12"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.TravelOrder}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding ExpenseReport.TravelOrderID}"
    ItemsSource ="{Binding TravelOrders}"
    ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource TravelOrderPickerConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedIndexChanged="PickerTravelOrder_SelectedIndexChanged">
</Picker>
```

My converter is this:

```
public class TravelOrderPickerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TravelOrder model = value as TravelOrder;
        if (model.Description == AppRes.None)
        {
            return $"--- {model.Description} ---";
        }
        else
        {
            return $"{model.Description} ({model.StartDate.ToShortDateString()} - {model.EndDate.ToShortDateString()})";
            //return model.Description;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Go from "#{model.ID} [{model.Description}] [{model.StartDate.ToShortDateString()}]" to a TravelOrder:
        try
        {
            //TODO
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to show in the selection list both the description (say, "Travel to Munich, Germany") and the interval, so people now what they are selecting. So in the end the picker should be populated with lines like "Travel to Munich, Germany (8/1/2024, 8/5/2024)"

On selecting a travelOrder, I populate two bound datepickers with the StartDate and EndDate so that these dates could be changed. At this point, the data is redundant - the interval is both in the description (in pickerTravelOrder) and in the two datePickers below.

How could I elegantly show in the picker the complete string "Travel to Munich, Germany (8/1/2024, 8/5/2024)" but, on selection, change the contents of that line to only "Travel to Munich, Germany"?

Comment: I can't understand your requirement clearly. Did you want to the different display between the selected result and it's displayitem or the different display between user scroll to the item and not scroll to the item? I see you used converter and selectedindexchanged event. Both of them can't work?

Comment: Hello, Liyun, I need to show on the vertical sheet showing when you click on the picker items like, for instance, "Travel to Munich, Germany (8/1/2024, 8/5/2024)" but, once you have selected that item from the list, have the picker close and show only "Travel to Munich, Germany" (i.e. without the date interval).

Comment: Did you try to remove the date in the selectedchanged event?